# Convergence to Stokes terminal velocity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, navier-stokes

Consider a spherical particle immersed in a fluid at room temperature. Starting from some time $t_{0}$, I turn on a spatially homogenous force on the particle. After some time $t$ I expect the particle to reach terminal constant velocity, whose magnitude is given by the product of the applied force and the mobility (or diffusion coefficient or inverse drag coefficient).

But how does the time-dependence of the velocity between $t_{0}$ and $t$ look like ? Especially if I do the experiment many times, and extract the mean time-dependence. What can you say about the convergence to the terminal Stokes velocity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fluid dynamic force on small bodies.** Small (enough) particles experience a drag that is approximately linear with the velocity,

\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{F}^f = - c \mathbf{v}^{rel} \ ,
\end{equation}

begin $\mathbf{v}^{rel} = \mathbf{v}^{body} - \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}^{body}(t),t)$ is the relative velocity of the particle w.r.t. the local velocity of the fluid.

**Equation of motions.** We can write the equation of motion of a point particle, using the second principle of dynamics
\begin{equation}
    m \dot{\mathbf{v}} = \mathbf{R}^{ext} \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{R}^{ext}$ is the sum of external forces acting on the particle, i.e. the sum of the constant force you apply $\mathbf{F}$ and the force due to the motion of the body in a fluid, $\mathbf{F}^f$.

If we assume that the particle is so small that its motion doesn't strongly affect the fluid around it, we can consider the fluid at rest, the relative velocity of the body w.r.t. the fluid coincides with the velocity of the body itself, and thus the force due to the fluid reads
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{F}^f = - c \mathbf{v} \ .
\end{equation}

**Equation of motions.** If this is the case, you can write the equation of motion of the small (point) particle as
\begin{equation}
  m \ddot{\mathbf{r}}^{body} = \mathbf{R}^{ext} = - c  \mathbf{v}^{body} + \mathbf{F}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  m \ddot{\mathbf{r}}^{body} + c \dot{\mathbf{r}}^{body} = \mathbf{F} \ ,
\end{equation}
or if you only care about the velocity and not the position,
\begin{equation}
  m \dot{\mathbf{v}}^{body} + c {\mathbf{v}}^{body} =  \mathbf{F} \ .
\end{equation}

Once you know the flow velocity as a function of time and the initial conditions of the particle
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{r}(0) = \mathbf{r}_0 \ , \quad 
    \mathbf{v}(0) = \mathbf{v}_0 \ ,
\end{equation}
you can easily integrate this equation.

**Integration of the equation of motions.** If the flow velocity is constant in time, you can perform the integration analytically, and find the result
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{v}^{body}(t) = \dfrac{\mathbf{F}}{c} + \left( \mathbf{v}_0 - \dfrac{\mathbf{F}}{c} \right) e^{-\frac{c}{m}t} \ .
\end{equation}
If you integrate in time, and prescribe the initial condition on the position, you can find the position of the body as a function of time as well.

**Terminal velocity.** You can easily find the terminal velocity, letting $t \rightarrow \infty$,

\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{v}^{term} = \dfrac{\mathbf{F}}{c} \ .
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you, this already helps. But what if I apply the force on all particles in the fluid ? And not only to one particle ? Does the exponential decay change significantly ?
Also, under what conditions does the linear relation between drag force and velocity holds ?

Comment: So, you're not interested in the motion of a small particle in a fluid, but in the motion of **all the fluid particles**, i.e. in the motion of the fluid itself. If it is so, please add another question, that clearly states your the problem.

Comment: You can't treat multiple particles independently if they are near each other. The flow around one particle creates forces on nearby particles. If you drop a bunch of small spheres, the cloud falls slower than a single particle. The cloud has a clean top edge because particles that get behind will catch up and then slow down. The bottom edge is diffuse because particles that get a little ahead will speed up and fall out of the cloud. Motion of all particles in the fluid is indeed another problem.

Comment: I have added a question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/784187/unbounded-fluid-under-constant-force